# Copy file from Windows to remote Linux server using SSH.NET SshClient

Tags: c#, .net, ssh, ssh.net

I am using Visual Studio and C# web application . I am trying to move a file from Windows server to a remote Linux server using SSH.NET `SshClient`. I am trying the below code, but the file is not getting copied.

```
var filespath = FUupload.PostedFile.FileName.Replace("\\", "/");
SshClient sshclient = new SshClient("hostname", "username", "pwd");
sshclient.Connect();
ShellStream stream = sshclient.CreateShellStream("cmsd", 80, 24, 800, 600, 1024);

Label1.Text = sendCommand("sudo su - wwabc1", stream).ToString();
Label2.Text = sendCommand("whoami", stream).ToString();
Label3.Text = sendCommand("cp /" + filespath + " /wwabc1/test/folder_one/test/", stream).ToString();
```

```
public StringBuilder sendCommand(string customCMD)
{
    StringBuilder answer;

    var reader = new StreamReader(stream);
    var writer = new StreamWriter(stream);
    writer.AutoFlush = true;
    WriteStream(customCMD, writer, stream);
    answer = ReadStream(reader);
    return answer;
}

private void WriteStream(string cmd, StreamWriter writer, ShellStream stream)
{
    writer.WriteLine(cmd);
    while (stream.Length == 0)
    {
        Thread.Sleep(500);
    }
}

private StringBuilder ReadStream(StreamReader reader)
{
    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();

    string line;
    while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
    {
        result.AppendLine(line);
    }
    return result;
}
```

I am not getting any error, but the file is not moved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot transfer a file between a local and a remote machine using shell commands.

Imagine, you are using an SSH terminal client (like PuTTY) instead. Can you use `cp` command in PuTTY to upload a file? – you cannot.

---

You have to use SFTP protocol.

```
SftpClient sftpclient = new SftpClient("hostname", "username", "pwd");
sftpclient.connect();
string localFilename = FUupload.PostedFile.FileName;
string remoteFilename = "/wwabc1/test/folder_one/test/" + Path.GetFileName(filename);
using (var fileStream = File.OpenRead(localFilename))
{
    sftpClient.UploadFile(fileStream, remoteFilename);
}
```